Why was Jim Turner called Captain Flint?
In the Swallows and Amazons book series, one of the most frequently recurring adult characters is the Blackett sisters' uncle, Jim Turner, whom they usually refer to as Captain Flint rather than Uncle Jim. Obviously, giving adventurous names to ordinary things (usually places, such as the "North Pole", but also people, such as the "natives" or "missionaries") is a big part of the storytelling in these books, so it makes sense that they gave him a pirate name, but why Captain Flint in particular? Was any reasoning ever given for this choice of name, rather than any other famous pirate (fictional or otherwise)?

Captain Flint is indeed a famous pirate, and one referred to in other fictional works as well. But I think what sets him apart from say, Blackbeard or Captain Hook is that in Treasure Island, he is not an active participant in the story. He set things up, it is his stuff people are after, but he is not there. This works pretty well for an absent uncle whose boat or study might be borrowed from time to time, or who might inspire various adventures without joining them.

The name "Captain Flint" first appears in Chapter 10 of Swallows and Amazons when the Swallows befriend the Amazons.
The Swallows had imagined that James Turner was a pirate,
and Nancy then decides he must be Captain Flint.

Titty broke in.
"Is your Uncle Jim a retired pirate?" she asked. "I said he was as soon as we saw him."
Nancy Blackett thought for a moment.  "It's quite a good thing for him to be," she said at last.
"But," said Titty, "you are pirates too."
"That's why he hates us. He must be Captain Flint. He knows what pirates are. He knows the day will come when he will walk the plank off the deck of his own ship when we have captured it."

That is, the name Flint was not part of the established fantasy developed by the Amazons before meeting the Swallows
(with the village being called Rio, Ruth being called Nancy, etc) but rather a fresh creation arising from their new friendship.
Stepping outside the frame: it shows the characters are familiar with Treasure Island, and use its matter to help build their own imaginary world.

Outside the book, Treasure Island seems to have been Ransome's go-to reference for pirate stories. In Swallowdale Jim tells how he discovered "Ben Gunn's cave" when he was a boy.

@ClaraDíazSanchez  Yes!  Another example: the parrot was Titty's clue that the houseboat man was a pirate, because Long John Silver had a parrot.
